# carrito, como hacer para que se añada uno por Producto en javascript(los Productos se llenan con un foreach en php)

Tags: javascript

bueno el tema es el siguiente que al añadir no me lo hace correctamente, como se aprecia en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]esta es mi funcion para añadir mi objeto al array, el tema q me añade id 1 , 1 y 2
es decir 2 15 y eso no se puede, como hacer para que funcione de manera correcta

```
  <template id="templateRowCarrito">
  <tr id="C_${id}">
  <td>${nombre}</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${cantidad}" id="PRE_${id}" 
  oninput="updatecantidad(${id},this.value)"  min="0"></td>
   <td><input type="number" value="${precio}" 
   oninput="updateprecio(${id},this.value)" min="0"></td>
   <td id="T_${id}"></td>
   </tr>

      function addToCarritoItem(id){

 let item = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
  if(item) {console.log("Repetido");
 }else console.log("NO Repetido");


    var id_ncap= document.querySelector('id_n').textContent
  var nombrecap= document.querySelector('.nombre').textContent
     var cantidad_disponiblecap=document.querySelector
      ('.cantidad_disponible').textContent

let Productos = {
  id: id_ncap,
  nombre: nombrecap,
  cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponiblecap

};
    let itemProducto = Productos;

  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
    if(itemCarrito){
   console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
       if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemCarrito.cantidad){
         return;
     }
    itemCarrito.cantidad++;
    document.getElementById("PRE_" +id).value=itemCarrito.cantidad;
     }
   else{
    itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon 
  para agregarlo al carrito
itemCarrito.cantidad=1;
itemCarrito.precio=0;
carrito.push(itemCarrito);

//renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
carrito_content.innerHTML+= 
   interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
  } 


 }
```

**o este otro intento**

```
     function addItemCarrito(newItem){


   for(let i =0; i < carrito.length ; i++){
        if(carrito[i].id === newItem.id){
          
          carrito[i].cantidad ++;
          const inputValue = InputElemnto[i]
          inputValue.value++;
          //CarritoTotal()
          return null;
        }
       
    }
  
    carrito.push(Productos)
    renderCarrito()
```

}

function addToCarritoItem(id){

```
    var id_ncap= document.querySelector('id_n').textContent
  var nombrecap= document.querySelector('.nombre').textContent
     var cantidad_disponiblecap=document.querySelector
      ('.cantidad_disponible').textContent

let Productos = {
 
  id: id_ncap,
  nombre: nombrecap,
  cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponiblecap

};
```

addItemCarrito(productos)

```
  }
```

```js
const Productos = [
{ id: 1, codigo: 1, nombre: "Producto 1",cantidad_disponible: 3,talla: 20, talla_ropa: "X"},
{ id: 2, codigo: 2, nombre: "Producto 2",cantidad_disponible: 4,talla: 40, talla_ropa: "XL"},
{ id: 3, codigo: 3, nombre: "Producto 3",cantidad_disponible: 5,talla: 30, talla_ropa: "S"},
];

const carrito = [];

//función para convertir un template con variables --> https://medium.com/@mrg101/this-is-great-thinking-2153c8982152
function interpolate(template, params) {
 template = template.toString().trim()
 const replaceTags = { '&': '&amp;', '<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;', '(': '%28', ')': '%29' };
 const safeInnerHTML = text => text.toString().replace(/[&<>\(\)]/g, tag => replaceTags[tag] || tag);
 const keys = Object.keys(params);
 const keyVals = Object.values(params).map(safeInnerHTML);
 return new Function(...keys, `return \`${template}\``)(...keyVals);
}
//==========================================================



function addToCarritoItem(id){
  let itemProducto = Productos.find(a=> a.id==id);
  

  
  
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
  if(itemCarrito){
     //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
    if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemCarrito.cantidad){
      return;
    }
   itemCarrito.cantidad++;
    document.getElementById("PRE_" +id).value=itemCarrito.cantidad;
  }
  else{
    itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
    itemCarrito.cantidad=1;
    itemCarrito.precio=0;
    carrito.push(itemCarrito);
    
    //renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
    carrito_content.innerHTML+= interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
  }
  
  
 
}

//renderiza todos los productos
function renderProductos(){
  productos_content.innerHTML="";
  for(let item of Productos){
    productos_content.innerHTML+=interpolate(templateItem.innerHTML, item);
  }
}



renderProductos();
```

```html
<template id="templateItem">
 <tr id="P_${id}">
  <td>${nombre}</td>
  <td id="Q_${id}">${cantidad_disponible}</td>
  <td><button onclick="addToCarritoItem(${id})">Añadir al carro</button></td>
 </tr>
</template>

<template id="templateRowCarrito">
 <tr id="C_${id}">
  <td>${nombre}</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${cantidad}" id="PRE_${id}" min="0"></td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${precio}" min="0"></td>
  <td id="T_${id}"></td>
 </tr>
</template>


<h1>Productos</h1>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Cantidad</td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="productos_content">
    
  <tbody>
</table>

<h1>Carrito</h1>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Cantidad</td>
      <td>Precio</td>
      <td>Total</td>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="carrito_content">
    
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Necesitamos que agregues de donde vienen y que valores tienen las variables `newItem` y `carrito`. @Cris223511.dev el `return null` es para terminar el analisis y salir de la función (_imagino que lo que se ve es parte del `addToCart`_)

Comment: La línea carrito.push(newItem) solo debe ser ejecutada en el caso de que en el bucle for, no encuentre ninguna coincidencia. Utiliza un booleano, el cual pones a True si entra en el if y luego pones un if antes de la línea "carrito.push" en base al booleano anterior.

Comment: ya agregue el codigo minimo verificable y las funciones y 2 intentos, llego al mismo problema

Comment: los productos llegan a la tabla productos mediante un foreach con php

Answer (score -1):

```
const Productos = [
   { id: 1, codigo: 1, nombre: "Producto 1",cantidad_disponible: 3, talla_ropa: "X"},
   { id: 2, codigo: 2, nombre: "Producto 2",cantidad_disponible: 4, talla_ropa: "XL"},
    { id: 3, codigo: 3, nombre: "Producto 3",cantidad_disponible: 5, talla_ropa: "S"},
];
  enCarrito = False;
  for(let i =0; i < carrito.length ; i++){
        if(carrito[i].id === newItem.id){
          
          carrito[i].cantidad ++;
          const inputValue = InputElemnto[i]
          inputValue.value++;
          enCarrito= True;
          return null;
        }
        
    }
    if (!enCarrito){
        carrito.push(newItem)
    }
    renderCarrito()
```

Comment: no, me sigue apareciendo ids o productos repetidos